# c++: STL Algorithms that are applied on vectors works for other container objects as well?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

Hi i have used some stl algorithms on vectors like find_if,count_if, sort, push_back etc. Now i want to make a generic code for all container objects(vectors,lists,maps,sets). Do i need to modify my stl functions for them or are they all same?

Comment: Some algorithms are implemented for one container individually because it gives more performance (for example, std::list has own sort function which more effectively than std::sort)

Comment: @user3514538 You can't use `std::sort` on a `std::list` at all, because it doesn't provide random access iterators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters `push_back` is not an algorithm. It is a method of some sequential containers like `std::vector` or `std::list`. However `std::forward_list` does not have such a method.

Standard algoreithm `std::sort` requires that the underlaying container had random access iterators. Some sequential containers like `std::list` and `std::forward_list` have their own methods sort. The standard algorithm `std::sort` can not be applied to these containers.

On the other hand such associative containers like `std;:set` or `std::map` are already ordered containers.

As for standard algorithms `std::find_if` or `std::count_if` then they can be applied to all standard containers because they are based on input iterators.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What are random access and input iterators?

Comment: @Geek Random access iterators allow to access elements of a container in a random manner. Input iterators allow to access elements only  sequentially.